# How to enable or disable characters of the keyword in a c program

Tags: c, input, keyword

I'm trying to get the control of the keyboard within a c program. I'm using Windows as os, and the program will be made in a console application.

My question is, is there such thing like for example a way to enable the num lock in a c program only when the program ask for a non-numeric value?

On the other hand, if the program ask for only numeric-value, then just enable only the num-pad.

I would like to know if this is possible and what are the steps that I should follow.

Comment: Googled but not tested: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/127190/howto-toggle-the-num-lock-caps-lock-and-scroll-lock-keys

Comment: When you say _keyword_ above, do you actually mean _keyboard_?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is there such thing like for example a way to enable the num lock in a c program only when the program ask for a non-numeric value?

Yes this is possible with the [SetKeyboardState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setkeyboardstate), [keybd_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setkeyboardstate) or [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) functions on Windows. The latter is preferred over keybd_event. It's a simple way to emulate keyboard input.

> On the other hand, if the program ask for only numeric-value, then just enable only the num-pad.

This becomes more complicated. It is possible in usermode but it's hacky. The correct way to do this would be creating a keyboard filter driver using the [WDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk). But unless you have a strong understanding of the driver API and the kernel model I also wouldn't recommend that route. The way to do it in usermode is to create a local keyboard filter using the [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) function with `WH_KEYBOARD` as the id. Inside the `LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)` callback you would check the scancode of the key that was pressed and if it was non numeric or any condition you preferred you would just return `CallNextHook` which jumps to the next procedure in the hook chain essentially ignoring the input you provided.